# Limit problem involving factorials and trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, factorial

The limit is: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n ln(\frac{((n+1)!)^{2n}}{n^{2n}(n!)^{2n}})+\frac{arctan(n)}{n}+\frac{sin(n)}{n}}{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}-4n}$$
After some calculations for the numerator i got to this conclusion:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2n}{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}-4n}$$
At this point it is difficult for me to work around $$(-1)^n$$
which is giving me some problems. Any hints? $$ $$
**I though about simplifying the n's which would lead to:$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2n}{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}-4n} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-4}$$

where $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \longrightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yeah i just thought about that, but i did not understand how you got the last part. Thank you

Comment: $$\left | \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \right | \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \longrightarrow 0$$